# Will different tables for different Users help in performence

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this `Posts` table. Somehow Read/Write ratio is 50:50. And we have to write very frequently.

Now suppose I am going to update 1000 post 500 users each, every minute. I think this will overcrowd the post table. So I am thing to have **n different table for Posts** like `Posts_a`, `Posts_b`, `Posts_c`.. and so on.

And I will have a `posts_table` field in the users meta data.

Now I want to know if that is a proper solution.

Comment: Maybe instead rethink why such updates are needed? Is the table properly normalized? To the question - no, it is not a proper solution, table names are *metadata* so you should not put *data* (the user identification) in there.

Comment: Don't split the data into separate tables. 500k rows, when properly indexed, is a minuscule amount of data these days

Comment: Are you designing for 500k reads or writes per minute i.e. over seven hundred million data accesses per day?

Comment: This is just the worst case, but actual is not much different. Around 30% of this load.

Comment: Do not use multiple tables rather use some sort of flags per user and if there are many user do indexed that column which would result in better IO.

Answer (score 4):

You only need 2 tables:

1. `Users (user_id (PK), username, password, email, created_at)`
2. `Posts (post_id (PK), user_id (IX), subject, body, created_at)`

Updates to either table would be done using the PK so they will be very fast. A simple JOIN can be used to retrieve posts of a particular user based on username, or a simple SELECT if the user_id is already cached.

Later on, any new features would be another table, referencing data in the aboves. Let's say you wanted to add a feature that tracked 'Post Likes'. Create a table `'post_likes' (post_id (PK), user_id (PK), created_at)`. Each time a user likes someone else's post, insert to this table.

Or allowed people to 'subscribe' to a particular user. `'user_subscribe' (subscribee_id (PK), subscriber_id (PK))`. When user #14 makes a new post,

```
SELECT 
  u.email 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN user_subscribe us ON u.user_id = us.subscribee_id 
WHERE 
  u.user_id = 14
```

then email all those people of the new post.

Until your "posts" table reaches the ~500-700GB range, you should be fine with this. After that, we can discuss proper sharding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, plan for the 'worst case' of 8K/sec.  2K/sec average is still rather heavy and cannot be done without some serious planning.

It is unrealistic to plan for 8K writes per second on day one.  It is better to build a system for a few hundred writes per second on day one, then *plan* on a serious overhaul of the system in a few months.

You don't really know that *this* will be the bottleneck.  You don't really know the "1000" will be that size, nor the "500".  If those numbers turn out to be 1000 and 5, you have one set of problems; if 10 and 500, you have a different set of problems.  You can't necessarily build one solution to fit both possible outcomes.

Yes, a single InnoDB table is the 'right' design to start with.

When (if) you really get to 1000x500, you will need Sharding, which will involve a major rewrite of the code, and multiple servers.  And you will need to separate the clients from the MySQL servers.  So, keep the "connection" code isolated and easily configurable.

`Posts` needs to be clustered on user_id, on the assumption that eventually you will be I/O bound and a common query will be something like "get all posts for a particular user".  So...

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
    post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, post_id),  -- to get clustering
    INDEX(post_id)   -- to key AUTO_INCREMENT happy
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Also, compress the `body` *in the client* and store it in a `BLOB`.  (OK, if you are going to use `FULLTEXT`, you won't be able to compress it.  Compression will save space, hence improve performance.  Compression *in the client* will offload the server.

If you are going to shoot high, you could consider starting with a Gelara cluster (See MariaDB or Percona).

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` is perhaps the best speedup -- but be aware of the possible data loss.  (Galera can compensate for that!)

Make `innodb_buffer_pool_size` about 70% of RAM.  This is also vital for performance of such a large amount of data.

If your "updates" are for "Like", put `likes` in a separate table -- this table will have most of the activity, and you don't want real "posts" stumbling over the "likes".  "Likes" are likely to be your first bottleneck; there are ways around it, but let's discuss that separately.

Answer (score 1):

I think separate table for each user is not recommendable.

If you use Innodb engine for "post" table then it will provide row level locking; performance issue should be avoidable.

Comment: So you mean innodb only locks the rows. Not whole table?

Comment: @anwerj, correct, InnoDB does row-level locking using indexes.